# Insert Special Symbols in \url

Tags: footnotes, urls

I have the following URL

```
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=density+destilled+water+23°C
```

Trying to insert this as a `\footnote` with `\url` I got an error. The same with

```
\footnote{\url{http:// [...] 23^{\circ}C}}
```

I hope you can help me!

Comment: `\url{http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=density+distilled+water+23%C2%B0C}`

Comment: @giordano Not enough in the case of a footnote. `\urldef` will also have to be used.

Comment: May be because of [pdftex - pdflatex, breakurl and unicode characters - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406762/pdflatex-breakurl-and-unicode-characters?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When URLs contain special characters, and you want to use them in an argument (even in a moving argument), the standard approach is yo use `\urldef`. Below I give to two options:

1. Use `\urldef`:

   ```
   \documentclass{amsart}
   \usepackage{hyperref}

   \urldef{\wxxiii}\url{http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=density+destilled+water+23°C }

   \begin{document}

   \footnote{\wxxiii}

   \end{document}
   ```

   The resulting footnote:

   [image]
2. Use

   ```
   http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=density+destilled+water+23%C2%B0C
   ```

   (which you can get with the help of your browser) and `\urldef`:

   ```
   \documentclass{amsart}
   \usepackage{hyperref}

   \urldef{\wxxiii}\url{http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=density+destilled+water+23%C2%B0C}

   \begin{document}

   \footnote{\wxxiii}

   \end{document}
   ```

   The resulting footnote text:

   [image]

Comment: Thank You! My Browser (Safari) shows the "°" in the URL.

Comment: The first option results in a wrong URL.

Comment: @giordano No. At least not for me using TeXworks' viewer, Evince, Acrobat Reader or Okular. In which PDF viewer do you get the wrong URL?

Comment: Okular 0.20.2.  The URL I get is http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=density+destilled+water+23Â°C  Instead, TeXstudio viewer read http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=density+destilled+water+23%EF%BF%BDC

Comment: @giordano So it seems more like a viewer problem?

Comment: Yes, but enough to avoid using special characters in URL, given also that the displayed URL is always different from the real link (like in your example) ;-)