# Problem with \url and fontenc?

Tags: pdftex, urls

Here is the input:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % my emacs saves this file with latin1 encoding
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

\urldef{\urlex}\url{https://e.g/page#§}

\noindent
The § sign appears as \u{g} in the URL:
\begin{itemize}
\item The URL: \urlex
\item A § sign in tt font: \texttt{§}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

And here the rather surprising result from a `pdflatex` run:

[image]

Note that Emacs properly saves the file latin1 encoded. It does not seem to be a problem with `inputenc` as the paragraph sign is properly set in the cm font and also outside of the URL in tt font. Does `url` fiddle around with the input encoding?

Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you know it's been almost three years that LaTeX expects `utf8` input encoding by default?

Comment: Workaround: use percent encoding for the URL https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87205/special-character-in-url-link

Comment: Thanks!  
(1) utf8 does not solve the problem but introduces new issues;
(2) I don't want ```hyperref``` because it also produces links from other references.

Comment: Looks like duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406762/pdflatex-breakurl-and-unicode-characters — I didn't try but you try it out and report if it solves your problem.

Comment: @Bernard: in principle, I agree. But with UTF-8 encoding, I also break my German Umlaute in ```\url{}```. That's why I stick with ISO-Latin-1.

Answer (score 1):

`url` has been written at a time when url's contained only ascii character. It doesn't handle input outside the ascii range. Input there will be passed simply through. `$` has (in latin1) the code `"A7`, and at that position T1-encoding has the `ğ`.

You get `§`  if you use as input `Ÿ` (as long as you use latin1 as input encoding, with utf8 it won't work):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % my emacs saves this file with latin1 encoding

\begin{document}

\urldef{\urlex}\url{https://e.g/page#Ÿ}
\noindent
The § sign appears as \u{g} in the URL:
\begin{itemize}
\item The URL: \urlex
\item A § sign in tt font: \texttt{§}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't proper urlencoding work, though? Meaning, use `%C2%A7` in place of the section sign.

Comment: @Ingmar well the OP doesn't want a link, but to print, so how to get the output is the main question.

Comment: +1: Would `\usepackage{xurl}` not also work?

Comment: @DrManuelKuehner look in the xurl source (ctan for example), it only adds extra line break point

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: thanks. That's exactly the pragmatic solution that I need. Cork encoding has the paragraph sign at ```"9F``` and using ISO-Latin-1 encoding in emacs is mute to this caracter, it doesn't encode it. So it appears as ```"9F``` in the ```.tex``` file and LaTeX converts it into the paragraph sign :-).